# Bitwise assignment operators in C#

Tags: c#, operators, bit-manipulation

Operators like `|=` and `&=` work as bitwise operators on ints and longs...

```
int a = 123;
int b = 234;
a |= b;
Console.WriteLine(a); // outputs 251
```

But on a bool, it's a logical operation:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;
a |= b;
Console.WriteLine(a); // outputs true
```

How do the `^=`, `&=` and `|=` operators decide which manipulation to use when being applied to different data types?

Comment: `But on a bool, it's a logical operation:`. Well, yes. But bools are single bits, and so a bit-wise OR is the same as a logical OR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler decides, based on the static types of the expressions involved.

Comment: What about cases with generics? Like `Foo<T>(T a, T b) { a |= b; }`

Comment: @PorkWaffles: You'd get a compile error, as `T` is not restricted to an interface/type guaranteed to handle the `|` operator. `"Operator '|=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'"`